# Media Query:Setting padding-top based for iPhone screen

Tags: css, media-queries

**Normal CSS:**

```
.container-step1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 12%;
  width: 50em !important;/*60em*/
  height: 35em;
}
```

For mobile I want to update `padding-top:25%;`. I tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .container-step1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
  width: 50em !important;/*60em*/
  height: 35em;
}
}
```

It didn't work. Safari is still referring to normal css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-device-width` VS `max-width`. `max-width` will work on desktop & mobile and `max-device-width` will only work on mobile.

Also, you only need to add the css that is updated in the query. You could remove all the redundant css.

```
.container-step1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 12%;
  width: 50em !important;/*60em*/
  height: 35em;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .container-step1 {
    padding-top: 25%;
  }
}
```